# Parse JSON multiple objects

Tags: java, json, parsing

I am trying to parse the below json but unable to do that as stack over flow error comes in.

Here is the JSON -

```
[{
    "Class": "1",
    "school": "test",
    "description": "test",
    "student": [
        "Student1",
        "Student2"
    ],
    "qualify": true,
    "annualFee": 3.00
}]
```

Here is the code which is failing currently.

```
String res  = cspResponse.prettyPrint();
org.json.JSONObject obj = new org.json.JSONObject(res);
org.json.JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray(arrayName);
String dataStatus=null;

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
    dataStatus = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString(key);
    System.out.println("dataStatus is \t" + dataStatus);
}
```

Usecases are:

1. To get the value key "class"
2. Get the value from Student
3. Get the value from school

I appreciate your help.

**update-1** 
Code more info on stack trace updated with below details.
cls = 1

error- `org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["student "] not a string.`

Stack trace-

```
public String getString(String key) throws JSONException {
        Object object = this.get(key);
        if (object instanceof String) {
            return (String) object;
        }
        throw new JSONException("JSONObject[" + quote(key) + "] not a string.");
    }
```

When I ran the code with the below answers, here its failing for student is not a string.

The answers I used from first two comments and both have the same error. I appropriate your help.

Comment: yet same. So I have updated question with update-1 with stack trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your json fragment is invalid - the last comma breaks the parsing. But the rest of the code is quite workable.

```
    String res = "[\n" +
            "    {\n" +
            "        \"Class\": \"1\",\n" +
            "        \"school\": \"test\",\n" +
            "        \"description\": \"test\",\n" +
            "        \"student\": [\n" +
            "            \"Student1\",\n" +
            "            \"Student2\"\n" +
            "        ],\n" +
            "        \"qualify\": true,\n" +
            "        \"annualFee\": 3.00\n" +
            "       }\n" +
            "]";

    JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(res);
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject block = arr.getJSONObject(i);
        Integer cls = block.getInt("Class");
        System.out.println("cls = " + cls);
        Object school = block.getString("school");
        System.out.println("school = " + school);
        JSONArray students = block.getJSONArray("student");
        System.out.println("student[0] = " + students.get(0));
        System.out.println("student[1] = " + students.get(1));
    }
```

should output

```
cls = 1
school = test
student[0] = Student1
student[1] = Student2
```

Comment: I am getting error when, its assigned res with json array.

Comment: Fix you json source first - the last comma in < "annualFee": 3.00,> phrase make the parsing fail

Comment: I fixed it, yet same.

Comment: Copy the comment's code and paste it to become your _main_ method's body. It is compilable, runnable and produce the output listed here. If then you have an error - post more details here.

Comment: yet same. So I have updated question with update-1 with stack trace.

Comment: Out of a resuorce you can make **either** JsonObject **or** JsonArray, not both. Your json fragment (res) represent JsonArray, so construct array from it. You can get typed properties from a JsonObject and indexed entries from a JsonArray, so keep an eye on the type of Json-construction you have. "student" key references an array, not a string property, so _get_ will return you an array, not string.

Answer (score 1):

Your **JSON** **reponse** root is **array** but you consider your JSON response as **JSON object**

Changing your parsing json code as below

```
String res=cspResponse.prettyPrint();
    org.json.JSONArray arr = new org.json.JSONArray(res);
    String dataStatus=null;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
        org.json.JSONObject obj=arr.getJSONObject(i);
        dataStatus = obj.getString(key);
        System.out.println("dataStatus is \t" + dataStatus);
        String schoolName = org.getString("school");
        System.out.println("school => " + schoolName);
        org.json.JSONArray students = obj.getJSONArray("student");
        System.out.println("student[0] = " + students.get(0));
        System.out.println("student[1] = " + students.get(1));
    }
```

Comment: It says `org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["student"]` not a string.

Comment: yet same. So I have updated question with update-1 with stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

```
    You can use simple JSONObject class and Simple JSONParser for parsing the JSON.

     1. Parse the JSON. 

          org.json.simple.JSONParser parser = new org.json.simple.JSONParser();
          org.json.simple.JSONObject parsedJSON = parser.parse(inputJSON);

     2. To get class: 

          String class = parsedJSON.get("Class");

     3. To get Students: 

          org.json.simple.JSONArray studentArray = parsedJSON.get("student");

    4. To Get School: 

         String school = parsedJSON.get("school");

    After the above steps, you can run a for-loop to print the class and students.
```